# Vertically append dataframes with unequal columns

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes like so,

```
>>>df1
    A   B
1   3   4
2   6   7

>>>df2
    C      D      E      F
1  20.0   30.0   61.2   29.1
2  40.0   50.0   33.8   36.4
```

Now what I want to do is append df2 vertically to the end of df1 so that it looks like this:-

```
       A      B
1      3      4
2      6      7
3      C      D    E    F
4    20.0   30.0   61.2   29.1
5    40.0   50.0   33.8   36.4
```

So far I have tried `pd.concat([df1, df2]) with axis = 0 and axis = 1`, `pd.append()` to no avail. The `pd.concat` appended `df2` horizontally to `df1` which doesnt fulfil my purpose.

`pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 0, ignore_index = True)` outputs this:-

```
   A    B    C     D     E     F
1  3    4
2  6    7
3           20.0  30.0  61.2  29.1
4           40.0  50.0  33.8  36.4
```

and `pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)` outputs this:-

```
   A    B    C     D     E     F
1  3    4   20.0  30.0  61.2  29.1
2  6    7   40.0  50.0  33.8  36.4
```

Any ideas or suggestions as to how I can do this? This is for Python3

Comment: To be honest, if C, D, E and F are still column names in the new dataframe, this doesn't make much sense.

Comment: can you please explain the logic of such a task, - very curious...
If it is the way you want tables to land on excel, - you do not need to append/contact them at all...

Comment: @9769953 i am actually collecting specific important data from different csvs and  appending them to only one csv after which ill be uploading them somewhere to be tracked daily. Also, yeah since I typed out the dataframe here on SO, I missed out on the empty top-left cell. My dataframes are just like how other dataframes are but since each one has been taken from a different file, each contains different columns and rows.

Comment: @9769953 i understand that yeah. But as you may have understood this is actually not my authority. Ive been instructed to do it like this. So however bad this process is, I need to do this. Will be great if you could help me out!

Comment: You say: "I have tried pd.concat([df1, df2]) with *axis = 0* and axis = 1", but next you say: "pd.concat appended df2 *horizontally*". That would just be `axis = 1`. Seems to me that `pd.concat([df1,df2], axis=0, ignore_index=True)` should simply achieve the desired output (it does for me). If you ran into an error using this method or achieved an undesired result, could you please update the Q with this information?

Comment: @9769953 like I said earlier, Im typing this out here by hand, so I may miss out on little details. My dataframes are just like other dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- **Option 1:**

In the comments, you mention:

> [I] am actually collecting specific important data from different csvs.

If possible, I would take advantage of adding `header=None` and `index_col[0]` as parameters to [`pd.read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html). This way, you can achieve the following quite easily:

```
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

# imitating the csv files here
file1 = StringIO("""\
,A,B
1,3,4
2,6,7
""")

file2 = StringIO("""\
,C,D,E,F
1,20.0,30.0,61.2,29.1
2,40.0,50.0,33.8,36.4
""")

list_files = [file1, file2]
list_dfs = list()

for file in list_files:
    list_dfs.append(pd.read_csv(file, sep=',', header=None, index_col=[0]))

df_new = pd.concat(list_dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(df_new)

      1     2     3     4
0     A     B   NaN   NaN
1     3     4   NaN   NaN
2     6     7   NaN   NaN
3     C     D     E     F
4  20.0  30.0  61.2  29.1
5  40.0  50.0  33.8  36.4
```

Now, at this point you could of course change the `df.columns` into `df_new.iloc[0]` (i.e. `['A', 'B', nan, nan]`), but that will leave you with duplicate `NaN` values as column names:

```
df_new.columns = df_new.iloc[0].values.tolist()
df_new = df_new.iloc[1:]

print(df_new)
      A     B   NaN   NaN
1     3     4   NaN   NaN
2     6     7   NaN   NaN
3     C     D     E     F
4  20.0  30.0  61.2  29.1
5  40.0  50.0  33.8  36.4
```

This is both highly impractical and also very likely to cause errors later on when you want to manipulate the data based on `column (index)` references.

---

- **Option 2:**

If the first option isn't feasible (e.g. no access to the original CSVs), you could achieve the same result as follows:

```
data1 = {'A': {1: 3, 2: 6}, 'B': {1: 4, 2: 7}}
df1 = pd.DataFrame(data1)

data2 = {'C': {1: 20.0, 2: 40.0},
         'D': {1: 30.0, 2: 50.0},
         'E': {1: 61.2, 2: 33.8},
         'F': {1: 29.1, 2: 36.4}}
df2 = pd.DataFrame(data2)

list_dfs = [df1,df2]

for i, item in enumerate(list_dfs):
    item.loc[-1] = item.columns
    item.index = item.index + 1
    item = item.sort_index()
    item.columns = [i for i in range(1, len(item.columns)+1)] # or start at 0
    list_dfs[i] = item

df_new = pd.concat(list_dfs, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

print(df_new)

      1     2     3     4
0     A     B   NaN   NaN
1     3     4   NaN   NaN
2     6     7   NaN   NaN
3     C     D     E     F
4  20.0  30.0  61.2  29.1
5  40.0  50.0  33.8  36.4
```

Comment: This is the answer I was looking for! Option 2 worked perfectly for me. Thanks a lot! Yeah, like you said Option 1 will lead to some other person facing errors when he tries to fetch data from the file I create.